# Is there a way to run a secondary ctest only after one has failed?

Tags: cmake, ctest

cmake version 3.23.1

We have a ctest that gets binary assets prior to running a series of tests. Occasionally the download (and ctest) will fail for various remote server reasons.

I would like to trigger a second test to download the assets from a different site only upon failure of the first.

Is there a "depends on" that I can trigger on failure?

It's not clear to me whether   FIXTURES_REQUIRED and/or RESOURCE_LOCK would be appropriate here, and it looks like these would only be available in cmake 3.7+

I've tried searching prior questions for duplicates, and didn't find any.

Comment: What does prevent you from merging those two test cases?

Comment: Why not just write a single script in your favorite programming language  that does exactly `trigger a second test to download the assets from a different site only upon failure of the first.` ?

Comment: adding on KamilCuk's point, I assume you could write the script in CMake using [CMake's `file(DOWNLOAD ...)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download)